# Is it correct to specify your actual internal IP in proxy_pass field in nginx?

Tags: nginx, node.js, google-compute-engine, proxypass

I'm now going to deploy my node.js app on Google Compute Engine via nginx, but after all the configurations are done, I hit the wall with "502 Bad Gateway" error.

Then, after digging out for so many hours, I finally found that the `proxy_pass` field in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/server.conf` should be your actual internal IP address displayed in GCE's console, instead of `http://127.0.0.1`. The conf file is the following (some values are just for the illustration purposes only):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://10.102.24.152:8888;
    }
}
```

However, all the tutorials I followed set the value at `proxy_pass` to `http://127.0.0.1`. But in my case it didn't work at all. The example of the tutorials are as follows:

- https://github.com/ShoppinPal/gcp-scripts/wiki/Setup-Nginx-on-Google-Cloud
- http://support.ghost.org/setup-ssl-self-hosted-ghost/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/problem-with-ssl-and-ghost

So I now wonder if it is the correct way to make the server working. Or does this lead to something prone to be valnurable in security? Or maybe `127.0.0.1` is the correct figure and there are other problems on my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, putting in the instance IP address is a reasonable thing to do.

You should be careful not to use the public IP, as you may get charged bandwidth charges. I'm not familiar with GCE, but in AWS you have an external IP that's routable on the internet and an internal IP within your network. There may be differences here between AWS and GCE, someone may correct me.

Comment: Thanks. Then do you have any guesses on why these linked posts use the `127.0.0.1` and otherwise don't mention changing the address altogether? For me it sounds awkward if the `127.0.0.1` doesn't work but the authers still keep it unchanged... Usually in tech community these authors kindly note it, as far as I know...

Comment: My best guesses (which probably isn't that good) are that 1) for some reason 127.0.0.1 isn't resolving properly on your machine or 2) whatever you're proxying to is bound to the IP address not the localhost IP. I'm not a network guy though.

Comment: So usually, both the localhost IP and internal IP work properly? Then which one do you recommend?

Comment: I recommend using the private network IP address over the public address, but beyond that whatever works seems fine.

Comment: Is the "private network IP address" an internal IP and "the public address" an external IP, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You want to avoid proxying to the public IP, but any internal IP that works is fine. It might be on GCE that using the public IP is fine, but your service should be bound to an internal IP not an external. Again, I'm not a network guy, so I'm happy for others to chime in and correct me.